# no output/pwd print - zip cracker Process finished with exit code 0

Tags: python, zip, output

```
import zipfile
import itertools
import string
from threading import Thread


def crack(zip, pwd):
    try:
        zip.extractall(pwd=str.encode(pwd))
        print("Success: Password is " + pwd)
    except:
        pass


zipFile = zipfile.ZipFile("/Users/Yamakasi/Desktop/PY/Mat1.zip")
myLetters = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation
for i in range(1, 1):
    for j in map("".join, itertools.product(myLetters, repeat=i)):
        t = Thread(target=crack, args=(zipFile, j))
        t.start()
```

#Hey @ll,
Process finished with exit code 0 but no output on may zip cracker? Greeting and Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you tried debugging and stepping through the "crack" function? This will allow you see if your code ever reaches the print statement.

Comment: hey, with debugging I got the same: Process finished with exit code 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your external `for` loop. It doesn't run at all.

`range(i, j)` runs from `i` to `j-1` so `range(1, 1)` will run from `1` to `0` which means don't run at all.

```
for i in range(1, 1):
    print("hi")
```

The above code doesn't `print` anything since the `for` loop is not entered once. If you want to run the `for` loop once, you should use:

```
for i in range(1, 2):
    print("hi")
```

Output:

```
hi
```